# Any sort of bridge between notion and org mode?

Tags: org-mode

Notion is a trendy new piece of software that seems to be following in slacks footprints. Slack was successful by taking `irc` and making it more corporate: easier to use, prettier, and adding useful features.

Notion is doing the same to wikipedia and to some degree org mode (structural editing, storing data in text files, code that can operate on the data structure, hyperlinks, multimedia settings). But it's no emacs ("clickity, click, click goes the mouse"). I was wondering if anyone had attempted to integrate this with `org-mode` and whether this was at all successful in doing so - I suspect many emaxers will be forced to use notion to communicate with other people, and notion will introduce many people to many of the ideas in org-mode.

I found this undocumented repo: https://github.com/RadekMolenda/org-notion
I've seen suggestions that integrate other web services with org-mode. With things like [org-jira](https://github.com/ahungry/org-jira), and [org-mediawiki](https://github.com/tomalexander/orgmode-mediawiki) - though suspect that these tools are at risk of "bit rot" that accompanies most screen scrapers.

*References*

- [Notion and org-mode](https://irreal.org/blog/?p=8713) blog post.
- [org-mode vs notion](https://www.slant.co/versus/8769/15790/%7Eorg-mode_vs_notion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notion famously took a while to release their api to the public. It entered open beta literally a month ago (see https://developers.notion.com/) so there's probably nothing thorough yet to bridge it with other software.

Comment: time to get to work!